# subfigure undefined control sequence error in latex

Tags: graphics

I have been using LaTeX for years, but today on sigchi template I am getting undefined control sequence error. I want to place my figures spanning two columns or even in a single column, but none works. Here is a minimal example code:

```
\documentclass{sigchi}

% Remove or comment out these two lines for final version
\toappearbox{\Large Submitted to CHI'13. \\Do not cite, do not circulate.}
\pagenumbering{arabic}% Arabic page numbers for submission. 

% Use \toappear{...} to override the default ACM copyright statement (e.g. for preprints).

% Load basic packages
\usepackage{balance}  % to better equalize the last page
\usepackage{graphicx} % for EPS, load graphicx instead
\usepackage{times}    % comment if you want LaTeX's default font
\usepackage{url}      % llt: nicely formatted URLs
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfig}



\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}

% llt: Define a global style for URLs, rather that the default one
\makeatletter
\def\url@leostyle{%
  \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sf}}{\def\UrlFont{\small\bf\ttfamily}}}
\makeatother
\urlstyle{leo}


% To make various LaTeX processors do the right thing with page size.
\def\pprw{8.5in}
\def\pprh{11in}
\special{papersize=\pprw,\pprh}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{\pprw}
\setlength{\paperheight}{\pprh}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\pprw}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\pprh}

% Make sure hyperref comes last of your loaded packages, 
% to give it a fighting chance of not being over-written, 
% since its job is to redefine many LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdftitle={SIGCHI Conference Proceedings Format},
pdfauthor={LaTeX},
pdfkeywords={SIGCHI, proceedings, archival format},
bookmarksnumbered,
pdfstartview={FitH},
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
breaklinks=true,
}

% create a shortcut to typeset table headings
\newcommand\tabhead[1]{\small\textbf{#1}}


% End of preamble. Here it comes the document.
\begin{document}

\title{title}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

Abstract
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}

Figure here
 \begin{figure*}
 \subfigure{\includegraphics{graph}}

 \subfigure{\includegraphics{graph2}}

 \subfigure{\includegraphics{graph3}}
 \end{figure*}

\balance


\bibliographystyle{acm-sigchi}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile,sample}
\end{document}
```

'

Comment: I found a solution. Might be helpful for other people as well: \begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3.1in]{figures/gpEcUND.eps}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3.1in]{figures/gpgTND.eps}}
\caption{Potential for 0.5 V bias.}
\label{fig:EcUND}
\end{figure}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's great that you found a solution :) Please consider either posting it as a self-contained answer, or deleting your question; it helps to keep the site tidy :)

Comment: You're loading the `subfig` package, which provides `\subfloat`; the `\subfigure` command was provided by the obsolete predecessor package `subfigure`. It's better to stick with the newer one.

Comment: I will post it as an answer once I get past the 8hrs new user limit. thanks.

Comment: On another note, I'd suggest using `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` so that the regular captions on figures remain unchanged from the original sigchi format.

Answer (score 27):

The `subfig` package requires the usage of `\subfloat`, rather than `\subfigure`:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3.1in]{figures/gpEcUND.eps}} 
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3.1in]{figures/gpgTND.eps}}
\caption{Potential for 0.5 V bias.} 
\label{fig:EcUND} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: prob. solved, thumbs up.

Comment: still getting !Undefined control sequence using sigconf

Comment: Only \subfloat does not work for me. Both \subfloat and \subfigure work!