# environment subfigure undefined

Tags: graphics, errors

I want to place two images side by side and I have seen [LaTeX figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side) but one of the answers give me the `Environment subfigure undefined` error and I haven't the slightest idea why. The idea is to place two subfigures side-by-side within a main figure.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass [10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{impedância Ri1.png}
  \caption{*caption*}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure} %

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{impedância ri2.png}
  \caption{*caption*}
  \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{*caption*}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm pretty sure this has been addressed before, but haven't yet found a good question to point to.

Comment: Maybe @barbarabeeton meant [this comment by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71652/subfigure-undefined-control-sequence-error-in-latex?rq=1#comment154384_71652)

Comment: @WillieWong -- Yes, that works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mix two different approaches together. You cannot use both of them at same time.
I include both methods to achieve same result:

> `\usepackage{subcaption}`

```
\documentclass [10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
Left is \ref{fig:sub1}. Right is \ref{fig:sub2}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{*caption*}
\label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}\hskip1ex
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{*caption*}
\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{*caption*}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> `\usepackage{subfig}`

```
\documentclass [10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
Left is \ref{fig:sub1}. Right is \ref{fig:sub2}.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[*caption*]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:sub1}}\hskip1ex
\subfloat[*caption*]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:sub2}}
\caption{*caption*}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: BTW, the subcaption package also supports \subfloat.